# How do I fix an Unresolved Exception in Visual Studio 2019 C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I know I've posted every day for like 3 days but I'm still a novice at this and will probably need help. I ran into an issue where whenever I debug something I keep getting an unresolved exception. The code is really long but I do have the class that it is part of. If someone could help me out I would greatly appreciate it.

This is where the issue keeps coming up:
[image: This is where the issue keeps coming up]

If you need a better view I will add the code below:

```
void Inventory::initialize(const int from)
{
    for (size_t i = from; i < cap, i++;)
    {
        this->itemArr[i] = nullptr;
    }
}
```

The issue is in the line where it has 'nullptr'

And this is the code that it is attached to:

```
class Inventory
{
private:
    int cap;
    int nrOfItems;
    Item **itemArr;
    void expand();
    void initialize(const int from);

public:
    Inventory();
    ~Inventory();
    void addItem(const Item &item);
    void removeItem(int index);
    inline void debugPrint() const    
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < this->nrOfItems; i++)
        {
            std::cout << this->itemArr[i]->debugPrint() << std::endl;
        }
    }

};
```

This is the entire Inventory.cpp page:

```
Inventory::Inventory()
{
    this->cap = 10;
    this->nrOfItems = 0;
    this->itemArr = new Item* [cap];
}


Inventory::~Inventory()
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < this->nrOfItems; i++)
    {
        delete this->itemArr[i];
    }
    delete[] itemArr;
}

void Inventory::expand()
{
    this->cap *= 2;

    Item **tempArr = new Item*[this->cap];



    for (size_t i = 0; i < this->nrOfItems, i++;)
    {
        tempArr[i] = new Item(*this->itemArr[i]);
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < this->nrOfItems, i++;)
    {
         delete this->itemArr[i];
    }
    delete[] this->itemArr;


    this->itemArr = tempArr;

    this->initialize(this->nrOfItems);
}

void Inventory::initialize(const int from)
{
    for (size_t i = from; i < cap, i++;)
    {
        this->itemArr[i] = nullptr;
    }
}

void Inventory::addItem(const Item& item)
{
    if (this->nrOfItems >= this->cap)
    {
        expand();
    }

    this->itemArr[this->nrOfItems++] = new Item(item);
}

void Inventory::removeItem(int index)
{

}
```

I hope this clears anything else up.

Comment: Where is `itemArr` initialized?.The loop that runs `this->itemArr[i] = nullptr` seems to assume that `itemArr` points to an array of (at least) `from + cap` elements.

Comment: itemArr is initialized in the second set of code that I posted

Comment: No, that's initializing `itemArr[i]`. But that's invalid unless `itemArr` was initialized first elsewhere.

Comment: would it be possible to just send you a copy of all of my code? im new to this and dont really know what im doing at all. i was trying to follow a video step by step and at the end this happened

Comment: BTW, the error is called unhandled exception, not unresolved exception.

Comment: i know i just accidentally typed that. and if thats all youre gonna say about it i would really appreciate different help besides something as trivial as a naming an error wrong on accident

Comment: @mashackl At some point in your code you have to have `this->itemArr = ...` (or the equivalent). It seems you don't have that so you are getting an error when you try to use `itemArr` because you never gave it a value. Any variable needs to be given a value before it is used. This is true for pointers and non-pointers alike.

Comment: ok yeah. ill give that a try real quick

Comment: @john I posted the rest of the code above. maybe that will help? I'm not sure. sorry I cant be of more help than this. like I said earlier I'm really new to this and don't know what I'm doing

Comment: @mashackl So you are initialising `itemArr` in the constructor. I'm afraid it's not obvious what the error is from the code above. None of the individual functions look to be obviously bugged (though some of them look a little strange). It must be the way you are using these functions in main (or wherever) that is the problem. What you need to do is  cut down the code until you have the smallest possible program that has the bug and the post the entire program here. This is called a [mre].

Comment: @mashackl `this->itemArr = new Item* [cap];` Change that to `this->itemArr = new Item* [cap]();` to initialize the pointers to `nullptr`.

Comment: @dxiv i tried what you suggested but it didnt work in the fixing at all. im still getting the Exception Unhandled error

Comment: You have reposted a post about this issue. Hope that can help you.